# Can a multiple of $15$ and a multiple of $21$ differ by $1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I know a solution to this question having to do with the fact that the $\gcd(15, 21) = 3$, so the answer is no.

But I can't figure out what is the reasoning behind this. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_Lemma

Comment: so every number a and b where a multiple of 15 and b multiple of 21 are multiples of 3. So they cant differ by 1

Comment: $3\mathbb{Z}$ is a set closed with respect to $+$ and $-$ and $1\not\in 3\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: How about this: Do you believe that a multiple of 3 and a multiple of 3 can differ by 1?

Comment: Let 15n be a multiple of 15 and let 21m be a multiple of 21.  Then 15n - 21m = 3(5n - 7m) is always a multiple of 3 and never 1.  Done.  What's harder to see is that there is *always* such multiples where 15n - 21m  = 3 and how to find them.  But it is true.  In this case 45 - 42 = 3.

Comment: As $15$ and $21$ are multiple of $3$, so is any linear combination of these. $15m+21n=3(5m+7n)$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's really simple, imagine the two numbers as $15n$ and $21k$.

Suppose that it's possible, then: $15n-21k = 1$

As you said $\gcd(15, 21) = 3$, so you can factor out: $3(5n-7k) = 1$.

On the left side, you have a multiple of 3, and in the other you have a 1, which isn't, so you have a contradiction. Note that inverting the subtraction won't change anything.

Answer (score 26):

A multiple of 15 and a multiple of 21 are both multiples of 3.

The difference between two multiples of 3 is another multiple of 3.

1 is not a multiple of 3.

Answer (score 1):

No: you can prove that $\text{gcd}(a, a +b) = \text{gcd}(a,b)$. Therefore, we have that $\text{gcd}(a,a+1) = \text{gcd}(a,1) =1$.

If we now consider multiples of $15$ and $21$, say $k \cdot 15, n \cdot 21$ with $k, n \in \mathbb{Z}$, such that $n \cdot 21 = k \cdot 15 + 1$, then we find that $3$ divides $\text{gcd}(k \cdot 15, n \cdot 21) = \text{gcd}(k \cdot 15, k \cdot 15 + 1) = 1$, which is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $15m > 21n$. Then you are asking if:
$$15m - 21n= 1.$$

This corresponds to:

$$15m = 21n + 1.$$

The term on the left is divisible by $3$. What about the term on the right?

Well, $21n$ is divisible by $3$ too. But, if you add $1$ to $21n$, it can't be divisible by $3$ anymore. 
Actually, you have the left term which is divisible by $3$ and the right term which is **not** divisible by $3$.

For these reasons, you can't find those numbers.

Similar arguments must be used to prove the same when $21n > 15m$. In this case, you should work on $21n = 15m + 1$.

Comment: I don't think you are using "WLOG" correctly: it should mean an *a priori* logical reduction from one case to another.  Here, the hypothesis is that we have two integers, one a multiple of $15$ and the other a multiple of $21$, and *it is a loss of generality* to assume that the multiple of $15$ is larger.  Maybe you mean "the other case is very similar" (which it is), but that's not the same as WLOG.  Anyway, you could just write $\pm 1$ in place of $1$.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what is gained by passing from the first equation to the second equation.  Already from the first equation we get that $1$ (or $-1$) is a multiple of $3$...which it isn't.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark  if $15m \le 21n$ then $15(-m) \ge 21 (-n)$ and if $15m = 21m \implies 15m - 21n = 0 \ne 1$.  So wlog can be justified.  But in my opinion, it must be justified.  I'm very weary about using wlog and I think it is a very good habit for students to get in the habit if using it to take a sentence or a half to explain *why* it follows.  Too often it is used incorrtly as an "I'm just going to do one case".  I wouldn't go so far as to say this poster is using it wrong but I wouldn't say s/he is using it right either.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Thanks for your comments. You are right, my answer is misleading. I should have written: "I show what happens if I assume $15m > 21n$. Then, the case $21n < 15m$ can be tackled using similar arguments". I'm going to fix this.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark this is the very first time that I feel that the downvoter is right :D thanks a lot again

Comment: The downvote wasn't mine, by the way.

Comment: @fleablood: I do think that beginning the proof with "Without loss of generality, we may assume $15m > 21n$" was wrong, precisely because it creates a logical gap.  As with many gaps, if you put other stuff in then it's not wrong anymore, but that's not much of a defense of the gap.  And for what it's worth, your suggested fix, although correct, is still not great style: you are dividing into cases to justify a logical claim of WLOG...so why not just divide into cases.

Comment: Anyway, I think you're right that WLOG is overused by students.  The more I think about it, the more I think the entire construction is at least slightly lazy: if certain cases follow logically follow from other cases, it is almost always better to say *why*.  Come to think of it, I don't see WLOG used much in research mathematics...

Comment: The OP was suggesting cases 15m $\le$ 21n leads to this and 15m > 21n is similar.  That is not wolog. It could be legitimate in a "proof is left to the student way" or a more obscure "identical up to symmetry" (which one should *never* show to students)  I was suggesting "$\gcd(-a,-b) = \gcd(a,b)$ and $-a < -b \iff a> b$ so wolog we may assume $15m \le 21n$" is wolog.  My rule of thumb is wolog is valid for labeling of if cases follow immediately from base cases.  In any event, I'd have avoided the entire issue as there is nothing wrong with negative numbers.